# Did I overdesign my MySQL database (users/companies/products)?

Tags: mysql, database-design, normalization

I'm new to database design, 
please give me advice about this.

1  [When should I use a composite index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823685/database-when-should-i-use-a-composite-index)

> im not sure what does index does, but
>   i do know we should put it when it
>   will be heavly loaded like for WHERE
>   verified = 1 and in search like
>   company.name = something. am i right ?

2 [MySQL indexes - how many are enough?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277865/mysql-indexes-how-many-are-enough/1277986#1277986)

> is it just enough ?

3 [Database Normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282510/database-normalization)

> is it just right?

[image]

Thanks.

edit*

rules.

> 1. each users( company member or owners ) could be a member of a
>      company
> 2. each company have some member of users.
> 3. there are company admins ( ceo, admins) and there are company members
>      ( inserts the products )
> 4. each company can have products.

for the number 3 i will add a bit at users_company
- 1 is for admin
- 0 is for members

Comment: Problem with this is that we see the tables you've designed, but don't know anything about what rules there are to the data you'll be storing in them.

Comment: What if a company has mulitple 'Phones','Addresses' or 'Emails'? May want to make a new table CompanyContact and link to a Company, thus allowing multiple contacts for one Compony. Well that's my 2c anyway

Comment: well the members or owners from the company will be the multiple contacts for the company, how about that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks good, well normalised, to me at least.

I notice that each product can only belong to one company.  If that's what you intended that's fine, otherwise you could have product have its own PID and have a product_company relation table, which would let more than one company sell a particular product.  Depends who administers the products I guess.

I did notice that the user table is called 'users' (plural) and the others are singular ('company', 'product').  That's only a minor thing though.

Comment: anyway i got a problem now, how can i insert a new company ? where should do i get the CID before im inserting the CID ?

Answer (score 0):

The only comment I have is that you may want to consider just adding a mapping_id column to your users_company table and making CID and UID foreign keys, and add a UNIQUE constraint.

This way you can have a distinct Primary Key for records in that table which isn't dependent on the structure of your other tables or any of your business logic.

Comment: I wouldn't think this is necessary; how would having CID and UID as the primary key depend too much on the structure of other tables?  Wouldn't adding another key de-normalise it to some extent?

Comment: This is to some degree an "opnion" question. I suppose it depends on the context of the project and whether the CID and UID are exposed as "business data". A table's key should be an internal-only piece of data that's simply used to key records in a table.

Multi-field keys can also make for more complex logic when working with the table.

Comment: hmm i so would like to do that, but they do have limits ( mapping_id as a int ), and do i have to add unique to each PK ? or PK and unique are quite the same ?

Comment: PKs are by definition unique. If you have other fields that you'd want to keep unique you can add a unique constraint to those as well.